# How to keep compiled ".js" files in separate directories?

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm new to TypeScript,
I have ".ts" files in different directories. When I run webpack all ".js" files are generated to the one directory.
How can I generate ".js" files to separate directories?

Comment: The question is a bit vague. Are you sure its the webpack thats outputting the .js files? Webpack normally puts it into a bundle with a fixed output. 
Otherwise you normally change this via the tsconfig.json settings, for example the "outDir" flag. Read more at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html.